# WordPress, вывод галереи через плагин ACF

Tags: php, html, wordpress, cms

На сайте есть галерея, это картинки превью, внутри ссылок. По клику на них фото открываются во всплывающем окне в полном масштабе.

Хочу сделать эту галерею через плагин ACF используя "Повторитель" и "Галерея".

Вот написал такой код:

```
<?php
$images = get_field('gallery');
foreach ( $images as $image ) {
   ?>
   <a href="<?php echo $image['sizes']['full'] ?>">
    <img src="" alt="">
   </a>
   <?php
} ?>
```

В ссылках в атрибуте href делаю вывод больших фото, а вот как быть с фото для превью? Неужели нужно создавать еще одну галерею для фото превью, для клиента это будет не очень удобно.

Можно ли, использую плагин ACF, сделать чтобы картинки для превью автоматически брались с основного фото, обрезались по указанным размерам и область обрезки желательно чтобы клиент мог регулировать? 
Как, например, это делается для стандартных миниатюр постов WordPress.

Или для этого лучше использовать не ACF, а какой-то другой плагин, специально заточен для галерей? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли, использую плагин ACF, сделать чтобы картинки для превью автоматически брались с основного фото

Укажите нужный размер миниатюры из доступных на сайте, например, thumbnail:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="">
```

Для полного изображения можно использовать просто url:

```
<a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
```

Если необходимо, в [документации по полю Image](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/) есть более расширенный пример (раздел "Customized display (arrray)").

> Или для этого лучше использовать не ACF, а какой-то другой плагин, специально заточен для галерей?

Как вариант, в ACF есть [поле Gallery](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/), но у него меньше возможностей, чем у Repeater.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так.

Используйте `image ID`   и этот код:

```
<?php  
    $image = get_field('image');
    $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

   if( $image ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
   }   
?>
```